# display image in Prawn PDF from Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, prawn, cloudinary

I use Cloudinary to store images. Images are uploaded via ckEditor(WYSIWYG) with the help of Carrierwave. Old approach, before using Cloudinary, is below. In new approach best I manage to make is just direct link which is working.

```
 require "open-uri"

 def old_approach
   devel_root_url = "http://localhost:3000"
   image open("#{devel_root_url}#{@publication.image.url(:thumb_for_new_publication)}")
 end

 def new_approach
   image open("http://res.cloudinary.com/long_path_/41bea7233824aba932adab8fb6f29d54371fa9d7_development.jpg"")
 end
```

Question is how PRAWN can bring pictures from Cloudinary that have been uploaded via ckEditor to Cloudinary?

Did anyne had this issue before?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I'm trying to make PRAWN generate PDF with pictures that have been uploaded via Carrierwave to Cloudinary. How to show path to Cloudinary,because all pictures are there?

Comment: What does `@publication.image.url` return?

Comment: This I used before start to use Cloudinary. Picture where stored locally and this brought them to PRAWN PDF.Now I add ckEditor and Cloudinary. ckEditor uploads pictures to Cloudinary, however Prawn losses its connection to pictures

Comment: But you're still using Carrierwave, don't you? According to the [docs](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave) the url helpers should work as usual.

Comment: I do use Carrierwave. I'm fine if I don't use ckEditor. ckEditor generates new Carrierwave uploader for storing pics and 3 models. No controller is generated, however @publication is my initial controller where users will add info to ckEditor. Did you get it?

Comment: here is question in google group, maybe it will help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prawn-ruby/abkcYHQuxr8